# Cardinality of a set within a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning, cardinals

Given a set $B = \{ \{1,4\}, a, b, \{\{3, 4\}\}, \{\emptyset\} \}$, 
find the cardinality of $B$

my answer is $5$, 
and it is from $\{1,4\}, a, b, \{\{3, 4\}\}, \{\emptyset\}$, which is $5$ elements
However I'm unsure if that is the correct answer because $\{\{3, 4\}\}$ has a set $\{3,4\}$ within a set.

The resource I found on-line says that:
Given $F = \{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\} \}$, 
the cardinality of $F = 3$,
where $\emptyset$ is one, $\{\emptyset\}$ is one, and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is another one.

Therefore I figure $\{\{3,4\}\}$ should also be counted as one cardinal as well.

Please give me some advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

The only way you could be wrong (in which case this would be a trick question) is if $a$ or $b$ was equal to one of the other elements of the set, e.g. $a = b$ or $a = \{\{3,4\}\}$.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: B = { 1, 1, {{1, 4}} }. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: @C.L, yes, something like that. Your approach to the problem is correct, I just wanted to emphasize that small detail. (Partially for the bad reason that a three word answer felt too short to me.) It is not so important at this case, but at some point you might learn about the *Kuratowski pair*, defined by $(x,y) = \{\{x,y\},\{x\}\}$, and there something odd happens when $x = y$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just a quick question: Would the cardinality of a new set B = { 1, 1, {{1, 4}} } still be 3, or is it 2 since 1 is repeated?

Comment: @C.L, unless it is specified that we are working in a non-standard set theory which allows repeated elements, we would have $\{1,1,\{\{1,4\}\}\} = \{1,\{\{1,4\}\}\}$, and in particular the cardinality of this set is 2.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what the elements of the set are, they only count once when determining cardinality. You determined the cardinality of your set correctly using this guiding principle.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. 
To be more specific, the cardinality of $B$ is $5$, the cardinality of $\{\{3,4\}\}$ is $1$ and the cardinality of $\{3,4\}$ is $2$.